# Java 8 check a hashmap equality of its keys to a list containing keys and return the hashmap value where they are equal

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I would like to iterate over a hashmap with Java 8, comparing its keys to a given list (containing objects with key ID) and return the values from the hashmap where the key of the hashmap and the key of the object in the list are equal. I can't figure this out.

I try to accomplish something like this:

```
someHashMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(something.stream().iterator().next().getID()))
    .map(map -> map.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the *key* of the map like your question states, or the *value* like your code does?

Comment: Hi Erwin! Sorry for the miss typing I am going to change it right now, yes I would like to compare the keys and return the values from the hashmap where the keys are matched.

Comment: You are overthinking here. Don't iterate the list of values, just use its contains method. If you are not overthinking because the problem is more complex, then your question is underdetailed. Because [mcve] missing.

Comment: Can you modify the original map? i.e. can you remove entries from it whose keys are not in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have these objects initialized:

```
Map<K,V> someHashMap;
List<K> something;
```

You can get a list of values from the `Map` by iterating over the `List` like this:

```
List<V> values = something.stream()
                        //.distinct() // include this if there may be duplicate keys
                          .filter(someHashMap::containsKey)
                          .map(someHashMap::get)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you want to iterate over the `Map` (which is slower), you could use:

```
List<V> values = someHashMap.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(e -> something.contains(e.getKey()))
                            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The first method preserves list order, the second one removes duplicates. Which one is appropriate depends on your usecase.

Comment: Thank you 4castle for you answer. In the list there are objects with ID field, how should I tell the stream that it should use that ID  during your solution? I am learning the java 8 now, and I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @MaxBeaver: You'd throw in an extra `.map(MyClass::getId)` before the `filter` (in the first method).

Comment: Simple and clean. I really like that you a) point out the unclear prerequisites b) show two solutions. Great post for an early Sunday morning.

Comment: If you need to optimize the second case, you might want to do `Set<K> someSet = new HashSet<>(something);` and then use `someSet.contains` instead of `something.contains` in `filter`.

Comment: In most cases, you want to avoid the double lookup by using `.map(someHashMap::get) .filter(Objects::nonNull)` instead of `.filter(someHashMap::containsKey) .map(someHashMap::get)`

Comment: @Holger I went the safe route in case there may have been `null` values in the `Map`, but that's true, in most cases there aren't any `null` values so it's safe to use `Map#get` to determine if there's a value.